# mysqlcppconn driver throwing memory leak

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, connector

[image]

these are my codes i dont know how to fix it hope someone can help me please
theres nothing wrong in my codes ig
this is my connect() call function
(mysqlcppconn-9-vs14.dll is in my path files)

```cpp
bool connect()
    {
        sql::Driver* driver;
        std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> con;
        try {
            driver = get_driver_instance();
            con.reset(driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root"));
        }
        catch (sql::SQLException& e) {
            std::cout << "Error connecting to the Database: " << e.what() << endl;
            if (con != NULL)
                con.reset(nullptr);//instead of disconnect
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

if (connect()) {
            con->setSchema("class");
            pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(q, w, e, r) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
            pstmt->setString(1, a);
            pstmt->setString(2, s);
            pstmt->setString(3, d);
            pstmt->setBlob(4, &f);
            pstmt->execute();
        }
```

Comment: `con` is a local object that will be destroyed right before returning from `connect`. You could try returning it from `connect`, then check if it is null or not. However, I'm not sure that solves the memory leak issue.

Comment: its still beeing null https://ibb.co/fdDyBbh

Comment: So, in your last image, the problem is that `get_driver_instance` returns an invalid driver instance?

Comment: yea this is my probleme

Comment: OK, that's a good start hehe You should then investigate what `get_driver_instance` does and try to understand why it's returning a null reference. Also, you should check `driver` for nullness before using it in `driver->connect`. If you can't find the solution to the problem, try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe [Compiler Explorer](godbolt.org) is a good place for that.